# Cross Referencing Data in Excel

Tags: excel, match, analytics, cross-reference

I am trying to start an advertisement analytics tool for my business. I have an Excel spreadsheet with 3 Sheets. Sheet 1 contains data about the advert clickers, Sheet 2 contains information about the product buyers and Sheet 3 should collect data based on cross-referencing data between Sheets 1 & 2.

The columns in Sheet 1 are as follows:

```
    A           B       C               D              E                F       G
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
product type, tag, click date/time, IP address, expiry time (days), expiry date/time
```

Each row represents a click. The expiry time (days) is determined by the product type, and the expiry time/date is the expiry time (days) added to the click date/time. The tag is a code that tells me where the link was found by the clicker.

The columns in Sheet 2 are as follows:

```
       A           B               C
---------------------------------------------
product type, IP address, purchase date/time.
```

Each row represents a product sale.

There are more rows in Sheet 2 than there are in Sheet 1.

There are three pieces of information that I want to match between Sheet 1 and Sheet 2: `IP address, product type` and whether the `purchase date/time` (Sheet 2) falls between the click `date/time` and the expiry `date/time`. I have made formulas that can verify whether this occurs but only for assigned cells in each Sheet.

I am trying to get Excel to match one row from Sheet 1 to all rows in Sheet 2. As there are more rows in Sheet 2 than in Sheet 1, there could be multiple matches for each tag as defined in Sheet 1, as customers may decide to buy more than one product after clicking the link.

Is there a way to try and match the data between the two Sheets and then collect the number of matches in Sheet 3? It may be easier to achieve if the IP address and product type are matched first and then to try and see if the `purchase date/time` falls within the click `date/time` and the expiry `date/time`.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated and thanks so much in advance. This has been bugging me for a while and I can't figure it out.

Comment: [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842) may be what you are looking for. If you are going for the check if the click was in time...

Comment: something like `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!D:D,Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!C:C,"<="&Sheet2!C2,Sheet1!F:F,">="&Sheet2!C2)` and then copy down (to check sheet2 against sheet1)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a good start for you.  With vlookup you can specify multiple criteria. First start by bringing in the useful data into one sheet - I would take column D and E of "sheet2" and use these:

In D:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2& " "&B2,Sheet1!$A$2:[BOTTOM RIGHT OF TABLE],3)
```

The 3 at the end specifies you want to return the click date.

In E:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2& " "&B2,Sheet1!$A$2:[BOTTOM RIGHT OF TABLE],6)
```

The 4 at the end specifies you want to retune the expiry date.

Once they are on one sheet, you can do an if statement comparison to see if the date (Column C) falls between your two dates (Column D and E).
Here is the if statement for that:

```
=IF(AND(C2>=D2,C2<=E2),1,0)
```

There is one shortfall to this, and that is if there are multiple matches for both product AND ip - this will only return 1, but otherwise you're talking about scripting something in VBA.

Comment: Hi Beutler, thanks for your suggestions. This is very helpful. For your last comment, does that mean that if there are several matches for IP and product type that I have to use VBA? I read somewhere about replacing the VLOOKUP function with a combination of MATCH and INDEX. Would that help me, or would I still have to use VBA to find several matches?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not terribly familiar with INDEX and MATCH.  From what I gather it has similar functionality, but has 4 benefits (non of which solve the issue you have): These are 1)You can look up to the left (vlookup has to have the look up value in the furthest left column) 2)Better safety against inserted/deleted rows. 3)Vlookup has a 255 char lookup limit. 4) INDEX/MATCH is faster.  None of which I think are huge advantages unless you have some serious data and a problem organizing it in a useful way.

Comment: Not sure if you tried the vlookup, but the other thing I forgot to mention is that I had to pull out the "."s from the IP address (find replace . for nothing).  If you want to take a shot at VBA, I imagine you'll have to have several clever loops (possibly using dictionaries) in order to organize the data in the desired way.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. Is it possible to use the VLOOKUP function to find and match a row using the IP address and the product type and then to get excel to paste the purchase date/time into Sheet 3 in the same row? Then after it's done that, can I run the same matching function but skip the row that's already been matched and find the next one that does? or would I have to do this in VBA?

Comment: The solution I posted should solve the first part of your question.  I really don't think there is formula manipulation that you can use in Excel to solve this without VBA, the iterative nature of searching through multiple lists like this is what programming is for.  Sorry :/

Comment: Ok. I had pretty much got that far. Do you have any ideas about the coding for what I want in VBA?

Comment: Yes... it's pretty convoluted, I'm actually working on a similar problem now, but it probably won't be usable until sometime late next week.  The basic idea, if you want to do some research, is to create a **dictionary** of **collections** (for each sheet you'll have a dictionary which contains each rows information).  Then you will have to have a nested **for loop** in order to compare each row of one sheet with each row of another.  Inside the inner loop will be your **If statements** to meet the conditions you requested. I'll try to post a concise version when I finish.

Comment: Amazing. You life saver. Do let me know when you've finished. I have a pretty good idea of how the logical steps would work in terms of transferring the data across but my VBA skills are practically zero. I'll look into it and see what I can come up with. Thanks for all your help. Been really useful

Comment: Hi @beutler . I have figured out the full code for my problem. This video really helped me get on the right path. Took a lot of testing and trial and error but this video got me well on the right path. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOxhRSCfHaw

Answer (score -2):

In excel you can refer cell based on sheet like this and make it on third sheet:

=Sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A2